# How to display all the dates for TFS Burndown (Hours) Chart

Tags: tfs

I am working with TFS Burndown Chart. By default, the burndown (hours) chart only displays the first 7 rows of dates and remaning/completed work. I checkout and downloaded the burndown chart. I noticed before I enabled the content, it only show the first 7 rows. After I enabled the content, I see all 19 rows. I read that you have to use the date filter but there is not date filter control to set the range. How do I set the excel report so it will show all date information (all 19 rows) on the web UI. I right clicked on the chart, I am ablel to do a 'Select Data' and edit the Remaining Work, Completed Work, and Ideal Trend. That change the chart to display all the dates, but when I uploaded the excel, it still only shows the first 7 rows. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You should consider upgrading TFS as support for 2010 ends in July 2015.

Answer (score 0):

On Row Levels it's set to show the Last 4 weeks; you can change it to a different value.